# Facebook Graph API Error (access token)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I'm getting the following error when I try to access the Graph API with my access token:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Expected 1 '.' in the input between the postcard and the payload",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

I'm grabbing the access token after successfully authenticating an app I'm working on.  I have accepted the permissions and I'm hitting the app's landing page.  The access token doesn't look like others I've seen online.  It doesn't have the '|' character in it.  It does have a period and some underscores along with the typical alphanumeric combination.

Comment: Check your access token using the debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug (I wonder what the error message means by “postcard” – internal FB developer joke?)

Comment: Thanks!  The debug tool definitely comes in handy.  In my case, however, the access token wasn't being obtained at the right time (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  The other developer I was working with used part of the raw signed_request object (not parsed) to form the access token.  After taken a gander at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), I quickly realized that you need to parse the signed_request object first before obtaining the oauth_token value.  After that was fixed, I was able to easily make an API call.

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure you are verifying the "code" parameter returned by Facebook before signing the request, not the "access token". Signing a request with a bad access token produced this error message for me.